# Android: MediaRecorder stop() freezes app

Tags: android-mediarecorder

I have an app to record screen videos. On some devices e.g. OnePlus 3t it works fine but on other devices like Samsung Galaxy s9 it freezes the whole app after stopping recording.

This is how I initialize the recorder:

```
    private void initRecorder() {

    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss")
            .format(new Date());
    File storeDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Videos");
    if (!storeDirectory.exists()) {
        boolean success = storeDirectory.mkdirs();
        if (!success) {
            Log.e(TAG, "failed to create file storage directory.");
            return;
        }
    }
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(storeDirectory + "/video" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(16);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);
    int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int orientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation + 90);
    mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
    mediaRecorder.prepare();
}
```

The start method is invoked on a button click. When this button is clicked again it stops recording an the following method is called. This it where it freezes everything.

```
    private void stopRecording() {
        if (virtualDisplay == null) {
            return;
        }
        virtualDisplay.release();
        mediaRecorder.stop(); --> freeze
        isRecording = false;
}
```

I have also tried to call the method stopRecording() in a separate thread. Then it does not freeze but the video is not saved. It seems to do heavy stuff in the stop() method that will never end. Any ideas?

Comment: did you find any solution for that?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: I was facing the same issue. May be the edited question can help you, in which i used separate thread for that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58061741/5110536